# Trying to show the map direction tracing instead of the list of directions in google maps (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps

I've looked around for answers to my question with no luck, so here it is:

How can I make my iPhone app launch Google Maps while loading directions from one place to another and show the map direction tracing instead of the default menu where you get a list of directions.

Here what I am currently doing:

```
_destination = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=Place+I+want+to+go+to"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_destination];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_mapsView loadRequest:requestURL];
```

This code shows by default the list of directions to follow to get to some place. The user has to press the "Maps" button to see the map of the two places, which is very annoying for what I need to do in my current app.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Are you running this on the simulator?  I think on the simulator, it will open Safari but on the device it will open the Maps app.

Comment: I am running it on both simulator and iPhone, with the same results: they both show me the directions list instead of the route, and it does not open Safari or Maps app (its basically the Mobile website of Maps integrated in my app)

Comment: OK, I thought you were using openURL but you're using a UIWebView.  Maybe there's a url query parameter that will make it go directly to the map.

Comment: That is exactly what I've been looking for, with no success so far..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=Place+I+want+to+go+to&output=embed&z=15"];
The output=embed will give you the map trace and the z= is for zoom level.

Enjoy